# MySQL with Haskell

Tags: mysql, haskell

I'm C# developer and I'm learning Haskell right now. I want to rewrite one of my projects in Haskell just for fun. In this project I have some work to do with MySQL so I want to ask: what is the best tool to use MySQL in Haskell. Also it will be awesome to look at some code how can I use it (I have Windows 7).

Comment: I would start [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Applications_and_libraries/Database_interfaces).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are plenty of different bindings and libraries for interaction with databases in Haskell, most of them are described on the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Database_interfaces).

If you're looking for a relatively simple binding to MySQL, then I'd recommend you have a look  at either of the following:

- [HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-mysql)
- [mysql-simple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mysql-simple)

There's a good chapter on how to use the HDBC interface in the [Using Databases](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-databases.html) chapter of the Real World Haskell book, which should be enough to get you started: there are plenty of examples of code there.

Comment: Damn! This total absence of any library with high level of abstraction makes Panda said. There needs to be some community effort put in this area.

Answer (score 7):

Also if you are interested in a more high-level library, take a look at [HaskellDB](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb). I also wrote a tutorial on how to set it up in [here](http://users.utu.fi/machra/posts/2011-07-15-haskelldb.html). And also chrisdones' [HaskellDB: A long tutorial](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskelldb-tutorial) is a good resource.